# resource cannot be found VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

[image]I have a VB.NET web project. When I'm clicking on menu item attached error comming. But that folder is there.
For other menu items there is no issue.
What can I do for this?

Comment: In that route there is file in that name..

Comment: Your error message it tells you ! "The resource you are looking for (or one of dependency) could have been removed, had its name changed ... " ...... Check step by step :)  URL root is your problem .. '/'

Comment: Already I have checked. File is there. But message showing. :(

Comment: stop iis - clean - recompile - and check compilation options of LoyaltyTracker.aspx

Comment: How to check 'compilation options' ?